# Automatically fetch links with Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext

This is kind of a random question, but in Textmate, there was a really nice feature. You could highlight a URL, press a keyboard shortcut, and it would automatically create `<a href="http://www.google.com" title="Google"></a>` for you.

I just searched tirelessly for about a half hour trying to find a similar package that would do it, but I can't seem to think of what search term to even look for. Anyone know off the top of their head a package that does this? I really loved that feature; it would hit the other website, grab the title attribute, and drop it in for you.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do that easily with standard sublime abilities. But I've found a package that is inspired by Textmate and it's called [HyperlinkHelper](https://github.com/sentience/HyperlinkHelper).

Simply install via PackageControl, restart sublime and you are ready to go. The default keyboard shortcut for generating a hyperlink out of the current selection is <kbd>STRG</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. Tested it in sublime 2 and works perfectly.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, thanks @apparat! Exactly what I was looking for!